# AJAX .html(response) not loading response

Tags: ajax

Been looking at this for about two hours - I can't figure out why it's not working as $('#add').html(response), but works fine when I change the function to $('.add').html(respoonse).

Any help is greatly appreciated...

```
function addc() {
id=$('#id').val();
$.ajax ({
    method:     "GET",
    url:        'addcal.php',
    data:       {"case":id},
    success:    function(response) {
                    $('#add').html(response);
                }
});
```

}

Comment: would be cool if you puts some html code but I think that you have something with **class=add** instead of **id=add**

Comment: How bout you `console.log` the `response` and see if you're *actually* getting anything.

Comment: i checked console - im getting the result but its not inserting it where its supposed to go.

Answer (score 0):

It would help to see the HTML for the element you're trying to update. But also, the "#" symbol will search for an item by id. The "." symbol is to find an element by class.